# How to place lines at the edge of the circle in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, geometryreader

I have a circle and I want to place small rectanlges at the edge of the circle. I want rectangles to placed on edge by only defining the angle. i.e if angle is 90, rectangle should be on top center of the circle. If say 120, it should be placed a little ahead of 90 degree's rectangle along with a little **tilt**, so rectangle and circle should be in sync.
I have tried alot to solve this, but I am unable to crack this yet.

Below is the code that I've written so far. Its basically a starter code, nothing more.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 10)
                        .frame(width: 220)
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 50)
                        .position(x: 0, y: 0)
                } //ZStack
                .frame(width: 220, height: 220, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.green)
            } //VStack
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: What I want it to look like]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: They are more like *lines* than rectangles, if their widths are fixed. Are some of the rectangles going to have a larger width than the circle's border?

Comment: This is something quite similar to the ticks of a clock face for example described [here](https://medium.com/dwarves-foundation/draw-watch-face-using-swiftui-a863ad347b2c)

Comment: @Sweeper, no those will be fixed. You are right, these are indeed lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest applying `.offset` followed by `.rotationEffect` to the rectangles.

Like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let radius: CGFloat = 110
    let tickMarkLength: CGFloat = 50

    private func tickMark(degrees: CGFloat) -> some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 15, height: tickMarkLength)
            .offset(y: -radius - (tickMarkLength / 2))
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(degrees - 90))
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 10)
                .frame(width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)
                .background(
                    Circle().fill(.green)
                )
            tickMark(degrees: 90)
            tickMark(degrees: 120)
        }
        .frame(
            width: (radius * 2) + (tickMarkLength * 2),
            height: (radius * 2) + (tickMarkLength * 2)
        )
        .background(.blue)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

In the code you provided in the question, you had a `GeometryReader`, although it didn't seem to be serving any purpose. However, if you were intending to derive the radius of the circle from the size of the frame it is contained in, then this is possible too. A few small adaptions are needed:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let tickMarkLength: CGFloat = 50

    private func tickMark(radius: CGFloat, degrees: CGFloat) -> some View {
        // implementation as before
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            let radius = (geo.size.height / 2) - tickMarkLength
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    // modifiers as before
                tickMark(radius: radius, degrees: 90)
                tickMark(radius: radius, degrees: 120)
            }
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
        }
        .frame(width: 320, height: 320) // just an example
        .background(.blue)
    }
}
```